# Define a "send-only" WebSocket server in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, websocket, spring-websocket

I would like to implement a **WebSocket** server in **Spring Web** (managed by **Spring Boot**) that allows a connected client only to receive a data stream, for instance a simple plain-text or a **STOMP** message.
I'm reading the **[documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html)** and a **[guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)** on the official web site, but in these cases, they consider a bidirectional conversation (also the client could send messages to the server).

1. For my scenario, represent WebSockets the right way (*yes, I'm a newbie in this field*)?
2. If yes, how can I implement a WebSocket as said? Should I define a
   `@Controller` and an *handler*?
3. Furthemore, is it possible to allow the communication only for a
   given client (by setting the route, the IP address, a token, etc.)?

Cheers, V.

Answer (score 3):

1. "Receive a data stream" is a technical solution for your scenario, but not the scenario itself. So I can't answer that question.
2. A controller is only needed for incoming requests. In your case the client would subscribe to a topic and the server publishes data. In order to do that you register a broker as described in **20.4.2 Enable STOMP over WebSocket**. Then you send data to that broker / topic as described in **20.4.5 Sending Messages**. The broker then delivers to the client. That would be a solution using STOMP. With direct Websocket usage you are on your own.
3. Yes, but that's not part of the websocket support of Spring. You can use Spring Security for that, if you like.

For what it's worth: A websocket connection is always bidirectional, regardless how you handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but I found a simple hack for allowing the server only to send data but not receive it.

I created a new Controller with the MessageMapping of "/wsname**"
which means all messages to the wsname websocket will be handled through this controller, and inside I threw an exception:

```
@MessageMapping("/wsname**")
public boolean Check(String message) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(message);
    throw new Exception("Forbidden");
}
```

the wsname was configured in the WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer implementation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WSConfig  implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {

    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/ws");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/wsname").withSockJS();
}
```

}